# codeigniter sql table conversion

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

*I have hypothetical table (for the convenience of the indices used real names)*
**table: product_price**
id: | product | valuta | location | price
------------------------------------------------------------------
01 | milk | EUR | London | 20 
02 | milk | USD | **Boston** | 19 
03 | milk | JPY | **Boston** | 180 
04 | apple | USD | **Boston** | 200 
05 | apple | USD | Springfild | 210 

*how get this array?*

```
array(<br>
 array('id'=>01, 'product'=>milk,  'location'=>'Boston', 'price_USD'=>19, 'price_JPY'=>180),<br>
 array('id'=>02, 'product'=>apple, 'location'=>'Boston', 'price_USD'=>200)<br>
);
```

Comment: Why in array id for the first element is 1? In db it's 2. Or it's no longer an id but rather just a sequential number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base query might look like

```
SELECT MIN(id) id,
       MIN(location) location,
       product,
       MIN(CASE WHEN valuta = 'USD' THEN price END) price_usd,
       MIN(CASE WHEN valuta = 'JPY' THEN price END) price_jpy
  FROM product_price
 WHERE location = 'Boston'
 GROUP BY product
 ORDER BY id
```

Output:

```
| ID | LOCATION | PRODUCT | PRICE_USD | PRICE_JPY |
---------------------------------------------------
|  2 |   Boston |    milk |        19 |       180 |
|  4 |   Boston |   apple |       200 |    (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2dba/4)** demo

Now I'm not a codeigniter expert but in codeigniter it might look

```
$result = $this->db
               ->select(
                'MIN(id) id,
                 MIN(location) location,
                 product,
                 MIN(CASE WHEN valuta = 'USD' THEN price END) price_usd,
                 MIN(CASE WHEN valuta = 'JPY' THEN price END) price_jpy')
               ->from('product_price')
               ->where(array('location' => 'Boston')
               ->group_by(array('product')
               ->order_by(array('id')
               ->get();
```